# Unable to open Bootstrap modal via code

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I use the Bootstrap framework and I want open a modal with a link

```
<a href='/test' aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top: 20px;" class="btn btn-success" role="button" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#test'> Įkelk savo profilio nuotrauką </a>
<div id="test" class="modal modal-wide">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Works fine, modal is opened but if I use in modal javaScript like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("ready!");
});
```

It's not working and the console is empty. JavaScript is not working on my bootstrap modal. If I don't use a link it works fine and I try to insert in modal jQuery is is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

The two are different things.

One is pure HTML and the other is javascript.
You can add them both like here http://www.bootply.com/giQj8UgpOt
Which does in fact log to the console and the button still works.  If you wanted to open the modal via javascript you would then call

```
$('#test').modal();
```

after `console.log` for example.
Like here: http://www.bootply.com/PQTWXMSPhX

Comment: And then i open modal get error in javaScript SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Comment: @user3546854 yes I just had a look and bootply doesn't seem to be working correctly.  The links don't want to load and when I try and make a new `ply` I can't seem to `save`.  Worth checking again a little later.

Comment: In the meantime you can look at http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/DTcHh/696/ and http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/DTcHh/697/

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand

Comment: open web in test.html when i open modal in modal.html and my javascript in modal.html not in test.html and when i put javascript in modal.html javascript not working

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't understand.  This is simple stuff to figure out though.  Just make sure you are including jQuery and bootstrap correctly and everything should work just fine.